Using the max function to solve Spivak:Prove $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) $ exist if $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) =\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)$ (Chapter 5, Problem 29)
The existence of $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) $ and $\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)$ imply the following inequalities...
$$0<x-a<\delta_1\longrightarrow|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$
$$0<a-x<\delta_2\longrightarrow|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$
If these to arguments are true,since $|x-a|=max(x-a,-(x-a)=max(x-a,a-x)$ it follows that
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\longrightarrow|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$ must be true if we make the convention $\delta=min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. Q.E.D
I would like to know if I'm correct in using the $max$ function to prove this theorem. I see no contradictions, but Spivak did not use it in his solution to the problem.
